# Getting a google api client error using the Uberi speech to text code

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use Uberi's speech to text code with the google cloud platform (GCP) speech to text API. I am getting the following error: `googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: speech  version: v1beta1`

Anyone know how to fix this error? Cant seem to find anything on Uberi github page. Was wondering if anyone has come across a similar error using the GCP or if anyone has a better way of embedding the google API speech-to-text code that works.

The GCP documentation isn't very clear!

I am using the following code:

```
recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()

audio_rate = args.rate
stream_buf = bytes()
stream_counter = 0


def recognize(stream_text):
    global args

    def logger(s):
        f = open('recognition_log2.txt', 'a+', encoding='utf-8')
        f.write(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("[ %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S ] "))
        f.write(s)
        f.write("\x0A")
        f.close()

    audio_data = sr.AudioData(stream_text, audio_rate, 2)
    GOOGLE_CLOUD_SPEECH_CREDENTIALS = r"""{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "xxx",
  "private_key_id": "xxx",
  "private_key": "xxx",
  "client_email": "xxx",
  "client_id": "xxx",
  "auth_uri": "xxx",
  "token_uri": "xxx",
}
"""
    try:
        result = recognizer.recognize_google_cloud(audio_data, credentials_json=GOOGLE_CLOUD_SPEECH_CREDENTIALS)
        print(result)
        logger(result)
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        pass
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results from GSR service; {0}".format(e))


def stream_audio(data):
    global args
    global stream_buf
    global stream_counter

    if stream_counter < args.buf:
        stream_buf += data
        stream_counter += 1
    else:
        threading.Thread(target=recognize, args=(stream_buf,)).start()
        stream_buf = bytes()
        stream_counter = 0


def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    stream_audio(in_data)
    return (None, pyaudio.paContinue)


stream = pa.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=audio_rate, input=True, stream_callback=callback,
                 input_device_index=args.device)
stream.start_stream()
while stream.is_active(): time.sleep(0.1)
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
pa.terminate()
```

Comment: Can you include what dependencies you have installed? Either your `requirements.txt` file or the output of `pip freeze`

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what the issue was, managed to read through a bunch of reported issues on Uberi's github page.

Simple solution was to just update the package to 3.8, I was running 3.6 which was using the old google cloud service.

Thanks Dustin!